# How do I prevent Eclipse from adding the 'final' keyword to a member variable declaration?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

When I type this

```
private MyKlass myklass;
```

and hit 'save' in Eclipse, it becomes this:

```
private final MyKlass myklass;
```

How do I stop Eclipse from doing this?

Comment: I want the same thing, BUT just on some specific cases (where there is bytecode processing and the vars cannot be final!!). I don't want to change the global eclipse code formatting...

Answer (score 22):

You need to disable that option in your 'save actions'.

right click your project > properties, then go to java editor > save actions. go to 'configure', 'code style' tab, and you have it on the bottom ('private fields').

Answer (score 16):

Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Save Actions - Configure... - Code Style - Use modifier final when possible

The same option can be found in Java - Code Style - Clean up.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to leave this feature enabled in general but turn it off for a specific field, I found a simple workaround. Just declare a protected method that assigns to this field.

`protected void preventFinal() {
  field = null;`
}

Answer (score 4):

You can go to Project --> Properties --> Java Editor --> Save actions , Uncheck "Enable project specific settings"

Answer (score 1):

There is Section called Save Actions in Eclipse Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor. There You can Configure Aditional actions - > (tab) code style - > Variable declarations -> edit use of final keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the field with `null`:

```
private File tempDir = null;
```